# EOF Error When Sending Mail With Sidekiq

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, sidekiq

When I try to send emails using sidekiq, it fails with the error:

```
EOFError: end of file reached
```

If I send the email using ActionMailer, the email gets sent no problem.

This works just fin:

```
InfractionMailer.alert.deliver
```

This, however, fails:

```
InfractionMailer.delay.alert
```

I am using SMTP through Office 365.

Sidekiq: 3.1.4 (also happened with 2.17.7)

Rails: 3.2.13

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it was an issue with the OpenSSL included in RVM's ruby-2.0.0-p353.  Upgrading to ruby-2.1.1 solved the issue